# Open source file in Electron DevTools in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

I am running an Electron app and developing it with VSCode and I have my debugging setup connected to VSCode, so that I can debug break points both in the main process and the renderer process. When I get error messages in my DevTools console I want to be able click on the source file on the right and have it open the target file in VSCode, and not in the "Sources" tab of the Devtools. This is what I am talking about:

[image: Source file reference]

I **don't** want it to open the file here, but rather in VSCode:

[image: DevTools file system]

Is this possible? How?

Comment: The devtools don't known about VS Code and they can't, because they're Chromium's built-in tools. I believe that there is no direct way to achieve what you're asking for, but I'm not writing this as an answer because someone might know a work-around.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Hm, I thought there maybe was some way to connect the "Debugger for Chrome" extension for VSCode to the DevTools to achieve this. But whatever, I am going to move on like this then.

Comment: There's no technical reason why this shouldn't be possible. Chrome dev tools could allow you to configure a program to be run when you click a link. VSCode supports opening files like `foo.txt:4`.